# Install4j - Silent installation without wizard

Tags: install4j

I'm looking to create a simple app that will just wrap a JAR, launch it and provide a JRE if needed. Install4j seems to work pretty well for that. We would only use the launcher part of it, as this is a really thin app and we don't care about installing it, as the JAR might change every time it's downloaded. We want it to be as transparent as possible, in the sense that it should just launch our JAR with no UI from the installer (besides a splash screen).

I've managed to get rid of most of the UI by selecting "Unattended mode" as the default execution mode. However, even after that and even if I select a Banner style for the GUI for the Installer, the Wizard screen always shows up (and the banner never comes up).

[image: Install4J Wizard UI]

How can I override this wizard screen with my own splash screen? This happens in both media files I've tried (Windows and MacOS bundle). I've disabled most of the Installer screens because they are not needed. The project configuration looks like this:
[image: Installation screen]

Answer (score 0):

On the Installer->Screens & Actions step, you can deselect the "Suppress initial progress dialog" property to hide this dialog.